# Adding 'badgeValue' to tab item in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Im wondering if it's possible to add a 'badgeValue' to a tab bar item in swiftui.

I have tried simply adding a circle shape along side the tab image inside a hstack inside the required tab bar item to no avail.

```
TabView{
                   SomeView()
                       .tabItem{

                           VStack{

                             HStack{
                               Image(systemName: "camera.viewfinder")
                               Image(systemName: "circle") //neither image appears
                              }


                               Text( "View one")
                           }

                   }
                   .tag(0)
}

I want to end up with something like this :
```

[image: I want to end up with something like this]

Comment: For me it shows the first image but not the second.

Comment: SwiftUI 3 (requiring iOS 15) now has a `.badge` modifier. [See this answer for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67894115/77567)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [TabView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview):

> Tab views only support tab items of type Text, Image, or an image followed by text. Passing any other type of view results in a visible but empty tab item.

If you still want to pursue this I would try to render it somewhere else or use pre-generated items, maybe 11 *prerendered* items (1 to 10 & an image for 10+) and show those as the content of the single *Image* allowed.

Another option would be to dynamically render it into an `UIImage` take the `UIImage` and put that into the image slot. You can probably use the badge-creation-code from [here](https://github.com/iosRevisited/SSBadgeButton/blob/master/SSBadgeButton/SSBadgeButton.swift) for this.

Another option is to show a number-image depending on the number of unread items and hope users will understand what is ment.

Comment: How would i use the dynamically rendered UIImage approach in a swiftUI context?

Comment: You got multiple options there. You can try to use `UIHostingController` to show a view and render that via normal UIViewController rendering methods or you can try out normal UIView -> UIImage rendering techniques. I bet there are more options. The simplest would probably be to ask sb to create prerendered images for you, or use some free existing ones. Much less time consuming to figure out.

Comment: Or overlaying two UIImages.

Comment: The problem with using multiple images - or images at all - is that you will lose color contrast between the notification and the image itself if you use the built in tint color attributes. You’d have to do something like using a clear color and having selected/deselected images for each tab bar item’s different states.

Comment: @eResourcesInc true. another approach would be to render the icon on top of the TabView inside a ZView, but you have to calculate the position of the badge yourself.

Comment: @Fabian that's correct, and it's sloppy at best. What I've done personally in my project is to just use the top bar's trailing view to store an Bell icon that shows when a user has notifications. It works for that case, but it's a shame we have to resort to things like that.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15 you can use a native badge modifier:

```
TabView {
    SomeView()
        .tabItem {
            ....
        }
        .badge($unreadNotifications)
}
```