# How to manage Tab bar badge count in SwiftUI 2.0?

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

[image]

Here I have use SwiftUI 2.0 and manage TabBar badge count. Reference of

https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swiftui-tutorial-showing-badge-on-tab-bar-item-d71e4075b67a

In Xcode 12.1 , the badge gets pushed up when the keyboard appears

[image]

How to mange this badge count When keyboard appear ?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) to your GeometryReader and/or the badge’s containing ZStack.

Your view is resizing to avoid the keyboard, which is the new default in iOS 14. Use the new .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) modifier to disable that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As of SwiftUI 3, you can use [the `.badge` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view-auxiliary-views) to add a badge to your tab item. This requires iOS 15 or later.

Examples:

```
struct Tabs_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("String tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("String")
                    Image(systemName: "text.quote")
                }
                .badge("hi")
                .tag("string")

            Text("Int tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Int")
                    Image(systemName: "number.circle")
                }
                .badge(123)
                .tag("string")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: screen shot showing a String tab item with a badge that says "hi" and an Int tab with a badge that says "123"]

You can use an `Int`, a `String`, a `Substring`, a `LocalizedStringKey`, or a `Text`. In my testing, the badge ignores any styling applied to the `Text`.